# Original derivation of the Josephson effect

Tags: superconductivity, second-quantization, josephson-junction

In my efforts to understand [Josephson's original derivation](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0031916362913690?via%3Dihub) of the effect that bears his name, I was led to Eqs. 3.68 on pg. 69 from Tinkham's book (Introduction to Superconductivity, McGraw-Hill, 2nd Edition). There he defines the operators

\begin{eqnarray}
\gamma^\dagger_{ek0} &=& u^*_kc^\dagger_{k\uparrow} - v_k^*S^\dagger c_{-k\downarrow} \nonumber \\
\gamma^\dagger_{hk0} &=& u^*_kSc^\dagger_{k\uparrow} - v_k^* c_{-k\downarrow} \nonumber \\
\gamma^\dagger_{ek1} &=& u^*_kc^\dagger_{-k\downarrow} + v_k^*S^\dagger c_{k\uparrow} \nonumber \\
\gamma^\dagger_{hk1} &=& u^*_kSc^\dagger_{-k\downarrow} + v_k^* c_{k\uparrow}.
\end{eqnarray}

which create definite particle or hole states (and which are evidently idential to the $\alpha^\dagger_{ek0}$ etc. operators used by Josephson). Then Tinkham states in the next equation (Eq. 3.69) that $\gamma^\dagger_{hk}=S\gamma^\dagger_{ek}$. **My first problem** is that I cannot see how this comes about. For example if you multiply he first equation in the above set of equations with $S$, you get $S\gamma^\dagger_{ek0} = u^*_kSc^\dagger_{k\uparrow} - v_k^*SS^\dagger c_{-k\downarrow}$. Now this is equal to $\gamma^\dagger_{hk0}$ only if $SS^\dagger=1$, i.e. if $S$ is a unitary operator, and it is not obvious to me that this must be so. (I know that $S^\dagger$ creates a pair and $S$ destroys the pair, so the end effect is that the state remains the same, but can we see purely on the basis of the anticommutation relations that $S$ is unitary? For example $c_{k\uparrow}c^\dagger_{k\uparrow}$ is also not the identity operator, although $c^\dagger_{k\uparrow}$ creates an electron and $c_{k\uparrow}$ destroys it, leaving no net change in the end.)

Now I come to **my second problem**. In Eq. 3.75 on pg. 72, Tinkham states that $c_{k\uparrow}^\dagger=u_k\gamma^\dagger_{ek0}+v_k^*\gamma_{hk1}$. (This equation is identical to the first equation in Eq. (1) in Josephson's paper.) Tinkham states that this follows from Eq. 3.68. When I tried to check this, I got almost the same result, but I got an additional multiplicative factor as well. My calculation goes as follows: Using Eq. 3.68 and after some algebra it can be shown that $u_k\gamma^\dagger_{ek0}+v^*_k\gamma_{hk1}=\mid u_k \mid^2c^\dagger_{k\uparrow}-u_kv^*_kS^\dagger c_{-k\downarrow}+u_kv^*_kc_{-k\downarrow}S^\dagger+\mid v_k \mid^2c^\dagger_{k\uparrow}$. The first and the fourth terms add up to $c^\dagger_{k\uparrow}$. But the second and the third terms do not cancel, since $S^\dagger$ and $c_{-k\downarrow}$ do not commute. Indeed, from the anticommutation rules we have $S^\dagger c_{-k\downarrow}=c^\dagger_{k\uparrow}c^\dagger_{-k\downarrow}c_{-k\downarrow}=-c^\dagger_{k\uparrow}c_{-k\downarrow}c^\dagger_{-k\downarrow}+c^\dagger_{k\uparrow}= c_{-k\downarrow}c^\dagger_{k\uparrow}c^\dagger_{-k\downarrow}+c^\dagger_{k\uparrow} =
c_{-k\downarrow}S^\dagger+c^\dagger_{k\uparrow}$. Putting it together we have $u_k\gamma^\dagger_{ek0}+v^*_k\gamma_{hk1}=(1-u_kv^*_k)c^\dagger_{k\uparrow}$ which, as mentioned earlier, differs from Tinkham's and Josephson's result by a multiplicative constant. So the question, why doesn't it match with Eq. (3.75) of Tinkham, or with Eq. (1) of Josephson?

Comment: Not clear what you're asking, what is $S$ ? Better to write it as some $k^\prime$ in your second problem, then you realise there are some $\delta$ distribution to deal with. The factor $1-uv^{\ast}$ is unitary, and it's just a phase/gauge choice as far as I can see. But you must do it carefully through the entire junction. Anyways, it's merely a definition of your $S$ as far as I can see. if $S$ is some sort of scattering matrix, it's natural to impose unitarity, in order to get current conservation. In case $S$ is some sort of canonical transformation, you need to impose unitarity as well.

Comment: $S^\dagger$ is an operator which creates a Cooper pair (Line 5, Pg. 69, Eq. 3.68 in Tinkham; or Line 2, Column 2, Pg. 1 of [Josephson's paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0031916362913690?via%3Dihub) where he calls it $S^\dagger_k$). With $S^\dagger=c^\dagger_{k\uparrow} c^\dagger_{-k\downarrow}$ and the usual Bogoliubov operators, I try to obtain Eq. (3.69) and (3.75) in Tinkham with the subsequent aim of understanding Eqs.(1-2) in Josephson. Please go thru the algebra I've outlined in my question to understand the specific problem that occurs when I try to do this.